# How to crossreference and combine values from many tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have three tables, tblTemplates, tblBLNALM and tblPrefs. They follow this structure:

```
tblPrefs:
--------------------------------------------
|  Pref  |  Derived-Template  |  Template  |
--------------------------------------------
|GA      |BLNALM_F03          |AIN_F03     |
--------------------------------------------
|HSSD    |BLNALM_F01          |AIN_F01     |
-------------------------------------------- etc...

tblBLNALM:
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Controller  |  Compound  |  Tagname  | BaseTemplate  |  Name  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|15CP42        |15F00       |HSSD30001C |BLNALM         |IN_7    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|15CP12        |15F06       |GA123456   |BLNALM         |IN_3    |
------------------------------------------------------------------ etc...

tblTemplates:
---------------------------------------
|  Template  |  Maintenance Override  |
---------------------------------------
|AIN_F01     |IN_7                    |
---------------------------------------
|AIN_F02     |IN_5                    |
--------------------------------------- 
|AIN_F03     |IN_7                    |
---------------------------------------etc...
```

What I need to do is to look if the characters before the numbers start in tblBLNALM.Tagname exist in tblPrefs, if they do, use this to determine what template it is. Then using this template and tblTemplates work out what Maintenance override it is.

The end result should look kind of like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Controller  |  Compound  |  Tagname  | Template  | Maintenance Override  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|15CP12        |15F06       |GA123456   |AIN_F03    |IN_7                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- etc...
```

My gut instinct was to use a few `EXISTS` statements and maybe nest them, but this hasn't helped, so where do I go from here?

I'm using msaccess 2010.

Comment: Use instead of tblBLNALM a query, where added calcutaed column with tagname prefix. Then just link this query with remaining two tables.

Comment: @SergeyS I'm not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: I've worked it out thanks, if you would like the credit, please submit it as an answer.

Comment: If you are having trouble writing what should be a simple query (SQL DML) then take a hard look at your design (SQL DDL) and you'll see a [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) violation i.e. "each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values".

Comment: @onedaywhen, unfortunately, it's not my data, I get it in the form I'm given and have to deal with that. Luckily, with the help of others it's now sorted

Comment: I then suggest transforming the data into relational format before attempting to write relational code to query it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string operations within SQL joins.

how about comparing if the **tagname** begins with your **pref**?

in SQL that would be:

```
SELECT tblBLNALM.Controller, 
    tblBLNALM.Compound, 
    tblBLNALM.Tagname, 
    tblTemplates.Template, 
    tblTemplates.[Maintenance Override]
FROM (tblTemplates 
    INNER JOIN tblPrefs ON tblTemplates.Template = tblPrefs.Template) 
    INNER JOIN tblBLNALM ON (tblPrefs.Pref = left(tblBLNALM.Tagname, len(tblPrefs.Pref)));
```

output will be as you described:

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------+
| Controller | Compound |  Tagname   | Template | Maintenance Override |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------+
| 15CP12     | 15F06    | GA123456   | AIN_F03  | IN_7                 |
| 15CP42     | 15F00    | HSSD30001C | AIN_F01  | IN_7                 |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: That's what I'm after, thanks, I didn't know that you could use string operations in joins!

Answer (score 1):

Join 3 tables: join `Template` fields in  `tblPrefs` and `tblTemplates`, then you should join `Tagname` of `tblBLNALM` and `Pref`, but here you cannot join fields directly, so create a query, where select all columns from `tblBLNALM` and add a calculated column, which returns starting letters from `Tagname` field and use it in join with `tblPrefs` instead of table.